# What does this statement really do?

Tags: python, random

I am new to python. Found a code online I am trying to understand. Can someone please help me understand what the following statement actually does?

```
    self.record = [random.choice([0.0, 1.0]) for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
random.choice([0.0, 1.0])
```

The `random.choice` method will randomly pick an element of a given sequence.  Here, it will randomly pick `0.0`, or `1.0`.

```
range(10)
```

This function will create a 10 element list (or iterable on python3)

```
[function() for _ in range(10)]
```

This is a list comprehension that will call a function 10 times, and place the results in a list.  The `_` is a python convention meaning "I need a variable here, but I won't use it's value"

```
[random.choice([0.0, 1.0]) for _ in range(10)]
```

This creates a list 10 elements long, where each element is either `0.0` or `1.0`, randomly chosen.

```
self.record = [random.choice([0.0, 1.0]) for _ in range(10)]
```

This places the 10 element list into the instance variable `record` inside your current class.

It is equivalent to the following code

```
self.record = []
for _ in range(10):
    num = random.choice([0.0, 1.0])
    self.record.append(num)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Starting to make sense now.

Comment: Just for the record, `random.choice()` won't accept an arbitrary [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable).  The argument is required to be a [sequence](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-sequence).

Comment: @SvenMarnach Good to know.  Updating.

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says:

```
self.record  =                    [                        random.
#self.record shall be a name for: a list consisting of one random 
choice(                     [0.0, 1.0]) for _
#choice taken from the list [0.0, 1.0], for each value (which we don't care about)
in  range(                                  10)]
#in a range from 0 up to but not including 10.
```